# Google App Engine Flexible Python service fails with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, importerror

I am deploying a Python3 app to Google App Engine Flexible Environment. I have all my dependencies listed in the requirements.txt file.

During deployment I received messages indicating the Google libraries have been deployed.
But, when the service is started it fails with
`from google.cloud import storage  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'` 
This runs fine locally.

Comment: Can you show your `requirements.txt` file content?

Comment: Flask==0.12.2
Flask-API==1.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud==0.32.0
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-storage==1.8.0
pandas==0.22.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include an additional file.
./setup.cfg
[install]
prefix=